# Does there have to be one createparameter per variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, createparams

I have a SQL statement that has a variable in it that is used twice because of an or in the statement. The question is when I create a `CreateParameter` statement for the var, do I need 2 statements one for each variable or can I use the same `CreateParameter` statement for both of the variable because they are the same value.

```
Select something 
From table
Where field1 = var 
  And field2 = 'test' Or field1 = var 
  And field2 = 'test2'
```

Comment: THIS: "can I use the same createparameter statement for both of the variable because they are the same value.?" You only need to define a parameter or variable once. Once it's created you can reference it as often as you'd like.

Comment: Rather than asking question, and waiting for answer, why don't you try it yourself??????  You would probably learn more if you try and find it out by yourself.

Comment: Your where clause doesn't make sense. You should add some parenthesis to it.